# Error using 'react-test-renderer' - Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jsx, react-test-renderer

I'm trying to implement Jest in my react app, but when I import the react-test-renderer, I get the error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

The only line in my App.test.jsx file is:

```
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer'; // ES6
```

The full error text is:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
>
>  at node_modules\react-test-renderer\cjs\react-test-renderer.development.js:177:27
>  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\react-test-renderer\cjs\react-test-renderer.development.js:17924:5)
>  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\react-test-renderer\index.js:6:20)
>  at Object.<anonymous> (src\components\App.test.jsx:2:52)
> ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003446/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-hasownproperty-of-undefined-react-dom) can help you

Answer (score 2):

Check your react and react-dom versions. They should be either different or outdated.